# Get EMUI version of a device programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services

During my application execution, how can I get EMUI version? 
Is there any system method to get EMUI version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible through accessing system properties like:

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
private fun Any?.readEMUIVersion() : String {
    try {
        val propertyClass = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
        val method: Method = propertyClass.getMethod("get", String::class.java)
        var versionEmui = method.invoke(propertyClass, "ro.build.version.emui") as String
        if (versionEmui.startsWith("EmotionUI_")) {
            versionEmui = versionEmui.substring(10, versionEmui.length)
        }
        return versionEmui
    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return ""
}
```

However, this is a private Api and if it is not suitable in your case, you can possibly use this workaround (would work for EMUI 9 and 10, however definitely wouldn't for EMUI 5 or below (~android 7)):

```
@TargetApi(3)
fun Any?.extractEmuiVersion() : String {
    return try {
        val line: String = Build.DISPLAY
        val spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ")
        val lastIndex = line.indexOf("(")
        if (lastIndex != -1) {
            line.substring(spaceIndex, lastIndex)
        } else line.substring(spaceIndex)
    } catch (e: Exception) { "" }
}
```

Any suggestions how to improve the answer are highly appreciated!